# How does JS interpret numbers at n decimal points

Tags: javascript

I came across some code today:

```
console.log(Math.ceil(3.000000000000001))
--> 4
console.log(Math.ceil(3.0000000000000001))
--> 3
```

What happened in the JS interpreter? What rules is it following such that the 1 gets "trimmed" in the second `Math.ceil`?

What I don't want is a bunch of links to floating point arithmetic... but what specifically is interpreted by JS.

Comment: have a look at [floats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic). this happens *before* `Math.ceil` so `3.0000000000000001 === 3` is `true`!

Comment: [Here's another great article](http://2ality.com/2012/04/number-encoding.html) about JavaScript's specific implementation of floating point numbers.

Comment: Is it because "the base for the scaling is normally two, ten, or sixteen" and there's 16 digits past the decimal?

Comment: I don't believe so. This question is about how floats get interpreted.

Comment: I think your question might have been better understood/received if you hadn't used `Math.ceil` which shifts the focus towards [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/11683). `console.log(3.0000000000000001)` and explicitly mentioning parsing of numeric literals would probably be better.

Comment: The second number has more digits than Javascript's floating point precision, so it's read as exactly `3.0`.

Comment: I don't think he should give any such examples at all if his interest lies in parsing implementation details - the described behavior is obvious for float64 if he "doesn't want [...] links to floating point arithmetic". However, i don't think he actually wants parsing implementation details - just my glass ball speaking.

Comment: Anyways, since it is apparently relevant to the discussion, here: [sec-static-semantics-mv](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-static-semantics-mv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript floating point numbers have a 51-bit mantissa, which allows for 16 decimal digits of precision. `3.000000000000001` has 16 digits, so the fraction can be included in the floating point value, and then `Math.ceil()` rounds it up to `4`. `3.0000000000000001` has 17 digits, so the fraction doesn't fit, and it gets rounded to `3.0` when reading it, and therefore `Math.ceil()` returns `3.0`.